# My let's arent saving when i assign a value to them

Tags: javascript, electron

I am using electron version 2.0.5 and ipcMain and ipcRenderer to pass data between my HTML and my main.js

```
let fna,lna,emaila,passa;
ipcMain.on('fname', function(er, fn){
  fna = fn;
  console.log(fn)
});

console.log(fna);
```

When I test it the function runs and when the first console.log runs.
I get the right data.
But when the second one runs I get undefined...
I do not understand electron very well as I am new to it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619966/how-to-call-a-function-with-a-promise and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619394/asynchronous-behavior-of-functions-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Your second log (fna) is called before the ipcMain.on is called, so it has not been assigned yet.

Comment: so how would i run that after the ipcMain.on ?

Comment: You need to call dependent code from inside ipcMain.on

Comment: so can i nest the ipcMain.on's ?

Comment: Exact scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619394/asynchronous-behavior-of-functions-in-typescript/51619480#51619480

Comment: You could also set a timer and poll the fna until it was defined.  Not the 'fastest' or most efficient way though

Comment: Yes, you define the function separately in that case.

Comment: thanks it works now just by moving that last cde into my ipcMain.on